# How to deal with multiple string values and compare those string values with the user input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, cpu-word, card

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LetterRandomiser : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char[] characters; 

    public Text textbox; 

    public InputField mainInputField;

    public string[] lines;

    void Start() 
    {
        char c = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];
        char d = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];

        textbox.text = c.ToString() + d.ToString(); 

        lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\lluc\Downloads\corncob_lowercase.txt");
    }

    void wordIsInFile(string word)
    {
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            if (word == item)
            {
                char c = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];
                char d = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];
                textbox.text = c.ToString() + d.ToString();
                mainInputField.text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                mainInputField.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    { 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == true)
        {
            wordIsInFile(mainInputField.text);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == false)
        {
            wordIsInFile(mainInputField.text);
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference to my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODoh.png)

My problem:

I want to make it so that the player has to guess a word that contains the two randomly generated letters (shown above the input field).

However as of right now, the player can input a word containing only one out of the two randomly generated letters and the program would still accept their input.

I don't want that to happen. I want to program the game so that it wouldn't accept the player's input until they include **both randomly generated letters**, not just one.

For example, in the image I am showing you, I can type in 'joker' and it would accept the input and generate a new set of randomly generated letters. However joker only has a 'j' and not a 'z' so it shouldn't be correct. The only words that should be accepted are words containing BOTH J AND Z, i.e. jazz

Comment: What is the use of your check for `Contains(text box.text)` if in both cases you do the same anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Contains()`.

Assuming a group of letters to compare in a string:

```
string lettersToCompare;
```

And that your user input is another string like:

```
string userInput;
```

You can do something like:

```
string lettersToCompare;
string userInput;

bool isMatchingAllCharacters = true;
//Compare each character of the string
foreach (char c in lettersToCompare.ToCharArray())
{
    //if the userInput do not contain this character, you already now it won't match every character.
    if (!userInput.Contains(c.ToString()))
    {
        isMatchingAllCharacters = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isMatchingAllCharacters)
{
    Debug.Log("All matched");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Something do not match");
}
```

You can avoid the `char-string` conversions if you use `LinQ`:

```
using System.Linq;

string lettersToCompare;
string userInput;

bool isMatchingAllCharacters = true;
//Compare each character of the string
foreach (char c in lettersToCompare)
{
    //if the userInput do not contain this character, you already now it won't match every character.
    if (!userInput.Contains(c))
    {
        isMatchingAllCharacters = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isMatchingAllCharacters)
{
    Debug.Log("All matched");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Something do not match");
}
```

Comment: Assets\Scripts\LetterRandomiser.cs(52,46): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: @greatvortex fixed, the previous code work without changes using LinQ

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: @greatvortex I've tested myself, so it seems to work. Tell me what errors you have

Comment: There are no errors but when I enter a word that contains only one of the two randomly generated letters, the program would still accept it. Code here... https://pastebin.com/UZ5n1dzV

Comment: @greatvortex Are you sure that your random letters and your user input are correctly filtered? Cause I'm checking and it works perfectly: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ItaAkH

Comment: @greatvortex same for the other answer btw .. posted the fiddle link there .. don't know exactly what your issue might be

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Intersect()` from `System.Linq()`?

```
string
    generatedLetters = "jz",
    userInput = "joker";

if (generatedLetters.Intersect(userInput).Count() == userInput.Length)
{
    //yes! good!
}
else
{
    //too bad..
}
```

[image]

`Intersect()` char count must match the `generatedLetters` char count to meet your conditions.

Comment: `Intersection() char count must match the generatedLetters char count to meet your conditions.` this is correct but in your code it is wrong ;) currently you are checking if the entire userInput.Length is a match ;) it should rather be `if(generatedLetters.Intersect(userInput).Count() == generatedLetters.Length)`

Comment: No errors when using your code. However, it would still accept an incorrect word. Here's the updated code. https://pastebin.com/NWDrg3dc

Comment: derHugo's correction still doesn't work.

Comment: @greatvortex oh sorry, I forgot the part where you were asking for word checking. I'll edit the answer with your code.

Comment: @derHugo you're right. I answered wrong because I forgot about word checking. Thanks for the point, anyway. :)

Comment: @greatvortex this also works btw see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nEDshp